# How to make Microsoft Lync instant messenger open reliably?

Tags: lync

Often I try to open Lync 2010, but nothing happens. On inspection in task manager, there are several `communicator.exe` processes in task manager. How can I stop this happening, so Lync window opens reliably?

Tedious workaround: kill and the communicators and try opening Lync again.

[image]

Comment: This has to be caused by something unique to your configuration because I use Lync 2010 every single day and don't have this problem.  One solution is to end those processes then start it up yourself through the use of a shortcut.

Comment: Others have this problem too http://grow-n-shine.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/why-wont-microsoft-lync-2010-start.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering this problem for the last few months. I am not sure whats causing the problem and how to avoid it completely.
Earlier when I would open MS Office/Outlook or SharePoint which are integrated with Lync because of Single Sign On, I noticed that Lync would run into this issue.

The workaround which has worked for me is that I first open Microsoft Lync after starting my computer and only then open any other programs like Microsoft Outlook/SharePoint.

Try this approach.

Comment: I have this exact problem: OL starts Lync which hangs. Is there a way to stop OL from trying to launch Lync? I have version 2010 of both on Win7 Pro 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Lync options, uncheck the box that says not to start Lync during Windows Startup.